# Given this code snippet, is the output CPU dependent or not?

Tags: c

```
void main() {

        if(-1 > 0U)
                printf("True\n");
        else
                printf("False\n");
}
```

Is it processor-dependent (big endian/little endian)?

Comment: Considering that the compiler will most likely optimize the condition away, I would say it doesn't really matter.

Comment: -1 is stored identically regardless of endianness on 2's compliment systems (I'm not sure there are any other modern systems)... 0xFFFFFFFF (with more or less F's according to the width of the value).

Comment: @mah Do all processors store negative number in 2's complement representation?

Comment: @user1517650 I'm unaware of any modern processors that do not.

Comment: @user1517650: ISO C also allows signed representations in 1's complement and sign/magnitude forms. But that is totally irrelevant for this case, since the standard also gives precise specifications of how to convert signed to unsigned values that do not depend on representation.

Comment: @user1517650: When asking questions about C implementations, you should not rely too strongly on the processor. Most C implementations naturally use features provided by the target processor, such as using two’s complement representations because the processor provides two’s complement arithmetic. However, nothing prohibits a C implementation from storing integers in one’s complement and implementing its own arithmetic. E.g., an implementation made to support archaic software might do this. It is the **C implementation** that determines its characteristics, not the **processor**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [C99 6.3.1.8](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.3.1.8) :

> [...] Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

Because `int` and `unsigned int` have the same conversion rank (see [6.3.1.1](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.3.1.1)), -1 will be converted to `unsigned int`. As per [6.3.1.3](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.3.1.3p2), the conversion result will be  `(-1 + UINT_MAX + 1) % (UINT_MAX + 1)` (arithmetically spoken) which is obviously `UINT_MAX` and thus greater than `0`.

The conclusion is that the C standard demands `(-1 > 0U)` to be true.

Comment: How does this answer the question about CPU dependencies? Also, you conveniently forgot to cite §3 of that text.

Comment: @Lundin: By deriving the behavior entirely from the C standard, it demonstrates there is no dependence on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A piece of code is Endian-Dependent **only if** it accesses variable `x` using a pointer whose type is smaller in size than the type of `x`.

For example:

```
int   x = 0x12345678;
char* p = (char*)&x;
char  c = p[0]; // 0x12 on BE and 0x78 on LE
```

Please note the emphasis on **"only if"**, in opposed to **"if and only if"**.

Hence, some examples may still work the same on BE and on LE:

```
struct s {int a; int b;} x = {0x11223344,0x55667788};
int* p = (int*)&x;
int  i = p[0]; // 0x11223344 in both cases
```

**Note:**

Bit-field structures may be compiled differently for BE and for LE.

But this can be referred to as a compiler-dependency rather than as an architectural-dependency.

Comment: Unions also expose endianness.